# httpd mod_rewrite redirect

Tags: redirection, httpd

Is it possible to create a rule for `mod_rewrite` which forwards queries to another site while saving original path in address-string?

Comment: You'll get more and better answers if you ask on serverfault.com or webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DougHarris: Please do not encourage cross-posting. If it is off topic it will be migrated to another site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not mod_rewrite expert, but have you tried something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That task solved simple over iptables. nat+masquerade - good solition